# Create Inrement Timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, momentjs

**Problem**

I want a timer that will accept the seconds, minutes, hours, days and start incrementing from there, say user open a page where the time fetched from server is say `2 hours 30 minutes 05 seconds`, now the javascript timer will start incrementing from this so it `02:30:05` then `02:30:06 .. 02:31:00` and so on.. as soon as seconds reach 60 minute is incremented

**What I have tried**

I have implemented the same using moment.js

```
var duration = moment.duration({
    'seconds': 30,
        'hour': 2,
        'minutes': 10
});
var interval = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() + interval, 'seconds');
    //.asSeconds() 
    $('.countdown').text(Math.round(duration.asHours()) + 'h:' + Math.round(duration.asMinutes()) + 'm:' + Math.round(duration.asSeconds()) + 's'); //.seconds() 
    $('.countdown1').text(duration.days() + 'd:' + duration.hours() + 'h:' + duration.minutes() + 'm:' + duration.seconds() + 's');

}, 1000);
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/UK6SM/)

**Requirement**

I want to know how i can implement it using **javascript/jquery** if possible else I will use `moment.js` one, I have looked around but all have countdown timer created from date, so the input will be `seconds, minutes, hours, days` and the counter will start from there in increment manner

Comment: What's wrong with the moment.js example?

Comment: Nothing wrong but I want to implement it using javascript/jquery if possible so that I dont have to load extra library

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I have already looked into this. It increments only seconds, i want to accept seconds, minutes, hours, days but I will give it a try to modify as per my requirement.

Comment: for fewer than 12 hours, it's easy to use a plain Date(): new Date( (2*60*60*1000) + (10*60*1000) + (30000) ).toISOString().split("T")[1].split(".")[0]

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for suggestions, it can be days also with 24 hour span and it is returning "02:10:30" not incrementing it

Comment: that;s just for turning ms into a human-readable time instead of all the yucky JS methods like getSeconds(). it can turn the function in the answer into a one-line solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something as simple as this:

```
var input = {year: 0, month: 0, day: 0, hours: 2, minutes: 10, seconds: 30};

var timestamp = new Date(input.year, input.month, input.day, 
                         input.hours, input.minutes, input.seconds);

var interval = 1;

setInterval(function () {
    timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);     
    $('.countdown2').text(timestamp.getDay()+'d:'+timestamp.getHours()+'h:'+
       timestamp.getMinutes()+'m:'+timestamp.getSeconds()+'s');
}, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);
```

Each interval, you're incrementing the time value of a Date object, then reading the hours/minutes/seconds back out and letting the native Date implementation worry about the conversion from raw seconds. Interval can be positive or negative, and as large as you like.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/VZFPf/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its working as per my requirement :), will implement it in my work and let you know. Cheers

Comment: Have added the fiddle just for demo purpose. Thanks its working great